# Convert query to list in django

Tags: python, django

I have this code in `views.py`

```
def prod_aff(request):
    queryset =Produit.objects.all()
    ca = sortiestk.objects.all().select_related('ref').select_related('codecateg').values_list('ref__codecateg',flat=True).distinct()
    ca1 = list(ca)
    print ca1
    for val in ca1:
        pp = sortiestk.objects.select_related('ref').select_related('codecateg').filter(ref__codecateg=val).aggregate(Sum('qtesrt'))
        print pp
    return render(request, 'produit/produit.html',{'nomc':getnomcat,'produit':queryset})
```

It displays:

```
{'qtesrt__sum': 8},
{'qtesrt__sum': 40},
{'qtesrt__sum': 10}
```

I want to put only the int values in a list. I tried `list(pp)` but it only showed `[qtesrt__sum , qtesrt__sum ,qtesrt__sum]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to flattern the query result on grouping, you can use `annotate` instead of `aggregate`

```
pp = sortiestk.objects.select_related('ref').select_related('codecateg').filter(ref__codecateg=val).annotate(qtesrt_total=Sum('qtesrt')).values_list('qtesrt_total', flat=True)
```

output will be:

```
[8,40,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list(pp.values())
```

This will get you a list of values from `pp`, which are exactly the integers that you want. If you run

```
list(pp)
```

you get the list of keys because this statement is equivalent to

```
list(pp.keys())
```

If you want to get both keys and values of `pp` into a list, you can do

```
list(pp) + list(pp.values())
```

Comment: No problemo, amigo!

Answer (score 0):

As per document [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), you can user just `list()` to convert query to list.